# Code is working differantly in vscode and jupyter notebook with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have the code which runs differantly in vs code and jupyternotebook.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import functools

        def my_func():
            for i in range(4):
                 time.sleep(5)
                 print(datetime.now().time())
```

I run the function as

```
def smap(f):
    return f()

f_inc = functools.partial(my_func)

pool = ThreadPool(3)
res = pool.map(smap, [f_inc])
```

Expected output:(VS CODE)

```
02:08:10.288722
02:13:10.288722
02:18:10.288722
02:23:10.288722
```

But output which is coming is:

```
02:08:10.288
02:08:10.298
02:08:10.299
02:08:10.2998
```

Comment: 1. Your posted code is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); it is missing necessary imports. 2. Function `my_func` is incomplete; the `except` block is missing. 3. `f_inc = functools.partial(my_func)` accomplishes nothing. One uses `partial` specifying positional and keyword arguments so that when `f_inc` is invoked it is as if `my_func` is invoked with those arguments.

Comment: f_inc partial is for multiproceessing in pool, to run differant functions at same time.. Edited the code..

Comment: No, in this case the `partial` is completely useless -- you could just as well code `res = pool.map(smap, [my_func])`. By the way, you are still missing two import statements and you have an indentation problem in your first code snippet.